Composition of ComposeView not working properly with WindowManager
I'm working on an Android service where I display an overlay view added through the WindowManager. The view itself is created using ComposeView. My goal is to create the ComposeView only once and then add or remove it as needed without having to recreate it each time.
The problem I’m encountering is that the first time I add the ComposeView, it works perfectly. But when I remove it and add it again in WindowManager, the composition stops functioning. This results in no animations at all and button clicks stops working within the ComposeView.
I've tried managing the LifecycleOwner and experimenting with lifecycle events, but the issue persists.

Here’s my code:
class MyService2 : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
    
    private val lifecycleOwner = MyLifecycleOwner()
    
    companion object {
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel"
    }

    private val windowManager by lazy {

        applicationContext.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    }

    private val layoutPrams by lazy {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE),
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
    }
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        lifecycleOwner.performRestore(null)
        lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)

        createNotificationChannel()

        val notification = createNotification()
        startForeground(579, notification)

    }
    
    private fun addComposeView() {
        windowManager.addView(composeView, layoutPrams)
        lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    }
    
    private val composeView: ComposeView by lazy {
        ComposeView(this).apply {

            val viewModelStore = ViewModelStore()

            val viewModelStoreOwner = object : ViewModelStoreOwner{
                override val viewModelStore: ViewModelStore
                    get() =viewModelStore
            }

            setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
            setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(lifecycleOwner)
            setViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner(viewModelStoreOwner)

            setContent { ComposeView() }

        }

    }
    
    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun ComposeView() {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
        ) {
            
            Button(onClick = {
                windowManager.removeView(composeView)
                lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)

            }) {
                Text("Remove view")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        intent?.let {
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra("stop", false)) {
                stopSelf()
            } else if (intent.getBooleanExtra("add_compose", false)) {
                addComposeView()
            }

        }
        return START_STICKY
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("My Foreground Service")
            .setContentText("Service is running in the foreground")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp) // replace with your icon
            .build()
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager?.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }
    }
}

private class MyLifecycleOwner : SavedStateRegistryOwner {

    private var mLifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)
    private var mSavedStateRegistryController: SavedStateRegistryController = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this)
    
    override val lifecycle: Lifecycle
        get() = mLifecycleRegistry

    override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry
        get() = mSavedStateRegistryController.savedStateRegistry
    
    val isInitialized: Boolean
        get() = true

    fun setCurrentState(state: Lifecycle.State) {
        mLifecycleRegistry.currentState = state
    }

    fun handleLifecycleEvent(event: Lifecycle.Event) {
        mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(event)
    }

    fun performRestore(savedState: Bundle?) {
        mSavedStateRegistryController.performRestore(savedState)
    }

    fun performSave(outBundle: Bundle) {
        mSavedStateRegistryController.performSave(outBundle)
    }
}

Things I've Tried

Adjusting lifecycleOwner events (ON_CREATE, ON_RESUME, etc.) during add/remove operations.
Verifying that ComposeView is only created once and reused.

What could be causing the composition to stop working after re-adding the view to WindowManager? Are there specific lifecycle events or strategies I need to manage better?

As a test, have you tried not reusing the existing ComposeView, but instead creating and populating a new one? I realize that is not your end objective. However, your use case is rather unusual. If things do not work even with a new ComposeView, then you know that the reuse is not the source of your difficulty.

@CommonsWare it works fine if we add new ComposeView each time. Just tested!
